# Transfer image capture photo from Phone gap to C# asp.net Web Service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, phonegap

Below is my j query function uploadPicOne()

```
        $(function() {
            var allVals = []; //for global check boxes
            $(document).on("click", ".click-action-for-event", function(e) {
        debugger;

                        //current i am calling this method for upload picture
                        uploadPicOne();

            })       
            });


        var uploadPicOne = function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(updateProfilePicService_one, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            });
        }

        var updateProfilePicService_one = function(fileUri) {
            SpinnerPlugin.activityStart("Loading...", { dimBackground: true });
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey = "image";
            options.fileName = fileUri.substr(fileUri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
            options.params = {
                "status": "B2",
                "iTrainingId": $("#iTrainingId_currentprogramme").val(),
                "session_date": $("#iTrainingDate_currentprogramme").val(),
            };
            options.headers = {
                "X-Api-Key": localStorage.getItem("auth_key"),
            };
            options.chunkedMode = false;
            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            console.log(options);
            ft.upload(fileUri, base_url + "uploadpic", win, fail, options);   

        }
```

Below is my webservice not sure its work for phone gap

```
        [WebMethod]
 public string uploadpic()
 {
     string msg = "";

     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn))
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("App_Service", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         try
         {

             var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
             IEnumerable<string> headers = request.Headers.GetValues("X-Api-Key");
             var auth_key = headers.FirstOrDefault();

             //  HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["image"];
             HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
             string saveFile = file.FileName;
             file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Trainer_Images/" + saveFile));

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paravalue", "14");
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", saveFile);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", auth_key);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", "0");
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3", "0");
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


             cmd.Dispose();
             con.Close();
             con.Dispose();
             //Context.Response.Write(JSONResult);
             //return d1.data;

            /// msg = "File uploaded";


         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             msg = "Could not upload file: " + ex.Message;

         }
     }
     return msg;
 }
```

I need to know my web service is correct or wrong. I am not able to run my webservice also, my requirement is send captured image file to my asp.net web-service and save to database, please help me to achieve my requirement or any suggestion or any examples related my need. The above jquery functions are working fine because the same app using into different application.

Today I have checked this code is not working through mobile showing loading after taking photo from mobile.

Comment: What version of ;.et Framework are you using? It's a MVC application or WebForms? What kind of error you got when try to run your web service?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making asp.net web service (asmx).It needs ajax enabled to be called from JavaScript.
For your project i think you should use  Asp.net mvc API 
check this article.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-image-to-server-using-web-api-2-0/